# Did Apple approve checking if an another app is installed on the device?

Tags: ios, url, instagram

I am using `Instagram` App feature in my app for sharing an image. For that i am checking whether the instagram app is installed on that device or not?. the code is below,..

```
if ([self isAppInstalled]) {

    Dlog(@"Instagram App Installed");

} else {

    DLog(@"Instagram app not installed");

}


- (BOOL) isAppInstalled {
    NSURL *appURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:appURL];
}
```

This URL `instagram://app` check the device for whether instagram app is installed or not?

This works fine on simulator and device also. But my doubt is this legally accepted by apple?. Because i haven't found any documentation about this. Someone help me to solve this.

Helpers are appreciated.

Comment: It is allowed. There is nothing wrong in that. You can launch app if they are exposing url scheme

Comment: Thanks Anil :-) Did you have any experience like this issue,..

Comment: If it wasn't allowed Apple would not have provided the `canOpenURL:` method. What you are doing is just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing now is just fine, for that purpose only apple has provided `url schemes`. Facebook SDK also doing the same for sharing,login etc if native fb app is installed. There is nothing wrong in that.

Here is the instagram documentation regarding that [check this](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/)